# ColdFusion 9 CFCookie error

Tags: coldfusion, runtime-error, coldfusion-9

Error message we get is as follows:

```
tried to access method 
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.isUnderCFThread()Z 
from class coldfusion.runtime.CookieScope
```

This started happening without any code changes.
I can post full stack trace if it helps.
It happens on a very generic call to cfcookie.

```
<cfcookie name="cookie_name" value="#cookie_value#">
```

We already tried restarting ColdFusion 9 service, IIS 6 and did full reboot of the server.

I appreciate any suggestions as to what it may be.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.isUnderCFThread()Z from class coldfusion.runtime.CookieScope at
coldfusion.runtime.CookieScope.bindName(CookieScope.java:90) at
coldfusion.runtime.CookieScope.bindAsScaler(CookieScope.java:81) at
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setSplitNameInMap(NeoPageContext.java:1389) at
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setValidatedSplitNameInString(NeoPageContext.java:1355) at
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setValidatedSplitNameInString(NeoPageContext.java:1349) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._structSetAt(CfJspPage.java:2242) at
cfCompareDetails2ecfm192447556.runPage(c:\websites\Includes\CompareDetails.cfm:21) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231) at
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722) at
cfcompare2ecfm930575567.runPage(c:\websites\compare.cfm:21) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231) at
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722) at
cfApplication2ecfc1238545388$funcSETUPREQUEST.runFunction(c:\websites\Application.cfc:119) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2582) at
cfframework2ecfc1986342034$funcSETUPREQUESTWRAPPER.runFunction(B:\websites\fw1\org\corfield\framework.cfc:1725) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2582) at
cfframework2ecfc1986342034$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(B:\websites\fw1\org\corfield\framework.cfc:763) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491) at
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337) at
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88) at
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequestStart(AppEventInvoker.java:258) at
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:367) at
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94) at
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70) at
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:201) at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86) at
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94) at
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101) at
jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106) at
jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42) at
jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286) at
jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543) at
jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203) at
jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428) at
jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

I think this is a relevant trace from cfusion-out.log

```
ava.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.isUnderCFThread()Z from class coldfusion.runtime.CookieScope
at coldfusion.runtime.CookieScope.bindName(CookieScope.java:90)
at coldfusion.runtime.CookieScope.bindAsScaler(CookieScope.java:81)
at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setSplitNameInMap(NeoPageContext.java:1389)
at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setValidatedSplitNameInString(NeoPageContext.java:1355)
at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setValidatedDottedName(NeoPageContext.java:1437)
at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.setValidatedAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:571)
at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.setAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:434)
at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.setAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:427)
at coldfusion.runtime.SecurityScopeTracker.setSecurityCookie(SecurityScopeTracker.java:126)
at coldfusion.runtime.SecurityScopeTracker.logout(SecurityScopeTracker.java:85)
at coldfusion.tagext.security.LogoutTag.doStartTag(LogoutTag.java:20)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
at cflogin2ecfm1599616868.runPage(C:\work\ColdFusion\cf9_u1_final_hotfix\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\login.cfm:11)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
at cfApplication2ecfm1920815415._factor5(C:\work\cf9_u1_final_hotfix\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\Application.cfm:210)
at cfApplication2ecfm1920815415._factor9(C:\work\cf9_u1_final_hotfix\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\Application.cfm:202)
at cfApplication2ecfm1920815415.runPage(C:\work\cf9_u1_final_hotfix\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\Application.cfm:1)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.include(CfincludeFilter.java:33)
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:297)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:201)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invokeNext(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:586)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.forwardInvoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:555)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.forward(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:203)
at jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet.service(FileServlet.java:323)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
at jrun.servlet.http.WebService.invokeRunnable(WebService.java:172)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.  And also post any messages from your `cfusion-out.log` file.

Comment: not sure what cfusion-out.log is? there is exception.log, application.log, server.log is that anyone of those?

Comment: The "cfusion-out.log" is on the ColdFusion server and will contain any errors, including the stack trace. Depending on your installation type, server versus j2ee, the log file will be in `{cf_root}\runtime\logs\coldfusion-out.log` or `jrun4\logs\cfusion-out.log`.

Comment: I suspect your code is being run inside a `<cfthread>`, and you cannot modify response (including cookie) because the response has already been returned.

Comment: Have you recently applied Hotfix APSB13-10 to your CF server? If so then Henry is probably probably right since this fix affects operations within cfthread. This would explain why this has suddenly started happening without code changes.

Comment: I did apply the hot fix about 2 weeks prior to this starting to happen. And no this is not withing cfthread. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: @IlyaFedotov did you ever figure this out? If so, please post as an answer so others can find it.

Comment: Okay, so you are using FW1, in the setUpRequest function, and this line is running: cfCompareDetails2ecfm192447556.runPage(c:\websites\Includes\CompareDetails.cfm:21) 
Can you post a few lines before and any wrapping tags? That method is not using cfthread, I take it?
Is this happening for all users & causing requests to fail? Or are you just seeing this in your logs as a silent error? 
It appears you are setting a session cookie (default) which should not really matter what client. But curious if it is all requests or certain requests.

Comment: We never really figured this out. We just removed cfcookie and did something else. Sorry for delayed response